# Limit to infinity of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Considering the sequence $a_n = \frac{2^n}{n^4} $ I am to show in my analysis exercices that the $ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =\infty $ using the definition of the limit. Now so far my textbook has not really defined logarithms, although I certainly know how to use the basic rules to give that $2^n > n^5 $ when $ n>{\frac{5ln(n)}{ln2}}$ and then use the fact that $\frac{2^n}{n^4} > \frac{n^5}{n^4} $ which diverges to infinity . But I am not sure how to rigorously say when that statement is true without appealing to graphs, not to mention that as I said earlier I haven't really "defined" logarithms. So my next idea would be to take another expression that is smaller than  $a_n = \frac{2^n}{n^4} $ with converges to infinity but I am having trouble finding one. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: appealing to your approach, can you prove that $2^n > n^5$ for sufficiently large $n$?

> Suppose $2^{n}>n^{5}$ for some fixed $n$. Then, $2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^{n}>2\cdot n^{5}=(2^{1/5}\cdot n)^{5}=(n+an)^{5}$ where $a=2^{1/5}-1> 0$. Now, pick $n$ large enough so that $an>1$.

Comment: As it turns out, $2^n>n^5$ for $n\ge 23$.  So, the induction starts there.  Then, we have automatically, $2n^5>(n+1)^5=n^5+\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{5}{k}n^k$

Comment: That is a great solution @par

Comment: Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem, we can see that if $n\ge 5$ then 
$$(1+1)^n\gt \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}.$$
If furthermore $n\ge 8$, then $(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)\gt (n^5)(2^4)$.  Thus for $n\ge 8$ we have
$$\frac{2^n}{n^4}\gt \frac{n}{(2^4)(5!)}.$$

Comment: Can you expand on that first line there? I am a bit confused.

Comment: By the binomial theorem, we have $(1+1)^n=1+n +n(n-1)/2!+n(n-1)(n-2)/3!+ n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/4!+\cdots$. (The sum terminates after $n+1$ terms). I threw   away most of the  terms, and only kept the $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)/5!$ term.

Answer (score 0):

Using induction we can show that $2^n\geq n^5$ for large enough $n$ . 
The inductive step looks like $$2^{n+1} = 2^n\cdot 2 \geq n^5 \cdot 2$$
$$\geq n^5\bigg(1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{10}{n^2} + \frac{10}{n^3}+\frac{5}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^5}\bigg) = (n+1)^5$$ for large enough $n$.

We can now use this by noticing that, $$n =\frac{n^5}{n^4}\leq\frac{2^n}{n^4}$$

And arrive at the result since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n = \infty$$